# Apache mod_proxy_ajp and tomcat7 (TomEE). Telnet 8009 from localhost works, but from other machine connection refused

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, tomcat

In my tomcat config, I have the following:

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Once I start tomcat, on that same box, I can `telnet localhost 8009` and get a connection. However, on the load balancer, I cannot telnet to that port.

I've disabled the firewalls on both boxes. I'm able to connect on port 8080. What gives???

Comment: Have you checked that IPTables? If you are using Linux.

Comment: write your comment as an answer so I can give you credit. It turns out some rules were stuck in iptables after we reinstalled it. We flushed it completely and switched to using the ufw frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPTables is only the case most of the creating this issue. :)